# Laravel auth()->user->posts()->create($data); > Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user

Tags: php, laravel

I've been following a tutorial for 2 hours, and now I have a problem. (Tutorial is using an older version of laravel)

I'm creating a instagram clone, and want to create posts.

```
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');
```

That's my web.php

```
public function store()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'caption' => 'required',
        'image' => ['required', 'image'],
    ]);

    auth()->user->posts()->create($data);

    dd(request()->all());

}
```

That's in my PostsController.php

Now, when I want to store a post, I get Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that you forget use () for ->user(), so try this ` auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);`

Comment: @Ramineghbalian Thanks a lot, I didn't see it. After 2 hours following a tutorial it's getting hard to focus. Thank you very much

Comment: you're welcome, so I post my comment as a answer.

Comment: `user` is a method, not a property: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you forget use `()` for `->user()`, so try this `auth()->user()->posts()->create($data);`

Answer (score -2):

when you are using authentication make sure to fetch data with your authentication middleware name

for eg

```
auth::(your middleware name)->user()->posts()->create($data);
```

you should use the authenticated guard so laravel can know that you are logged in with the role you’ve set for the admin or user like user can be 0 and admin can be 1 so use auth so laravel can know which permission it has